# Returning aggregates over CASE expressions from a function

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, return-value, aggregate-filter

I want to return four conditional aggregates from a function. I tried using `CASE` expressions. My SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_grade(IN integer, out integer,out integer,out      integer,out integer)  AS
$BODY$
begin
    select 
    sum(case when t.pirority = 66 then 1 else 0 end) as I ,
    sum(case when t.pirority = 67 then 1 else 0 end) as II,
    sum(case when t.pirority = 68 then 1 else 0 end) as III,
    sum(case when t.pirority = 225 then 1 else 0 end) as IIII 
    from dt_info t 
    where t.registrant = $1
end
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
```

When I use:

```
select * from get_grade(22);
```

it doesn't work as expected.

Also tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_grade(IN integer) returns setof record AS
$BODY$
    select
    sum(case when t.pirority = 66 then 1 else 0 end) as I,
    sum(case when t.pirority = 67 then 1 else 0 end) as II,
    sum(case when t.pirority = 68 then 1 else 0 end) as III,
    sum(case when t.pirority = 225 then 1 else 0 end) as IIII
    from dt_info t 
    where t.registrant = $1
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'sql' VOLATILE;
```

Then I execute:

```
select * from get_grade(25) as (v1 integer, v2 integer, v3 integer, v4 integer)
```

Error:

> ERROR:  function return row and query-specified return row do not match

How to get this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_grade(int)
  RETURNS TABLE (i int, ii int, iii int, iiii int)
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT count(t.priority =  66 OR NULL)::int  -- AS I
     , count(t.priority =  67 OR NULL)::int  -- AS II
     , count(t.priority =  68 OR NULL)::int  -- AS III
     , count(t.priority = 225 OR NULL)::int  -- AS IIII
FROM   dt_info t 
WHERE  t.registrant = $1;
$func$;
```

You *can* write a simple query like this with `LANGUAGE plpgsql`. You can also just use **`LANGUAGE sql`**. Either has pros and cons. Showing an SQL function. Don't quote the language name. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#id-1.9.3.67.6)

> Enclosing the name in single quotes is deprecated and requires matching case.

**Column aliases inside the function body** are not visible outside. They only serve as documentation in this case. Use **named** `OUT` parameters or they get default names. `RETURNS TABLE` makes it a set-returning function and requires columns names in any case.

`OUT` parameters are visible inside every DML SQL statement inside the function body. Table-qualify column names that would otherwise **conflict with `OUT` parameter names**. Don't use aliases that would conflict. I commented out your aliases to be clear (though modern versions of Postgres wouldn't conflict there).

Data types of returned columns have to match the declaration in the header exactly. `sum()` or `count()` return `bigint`. You have to **cast to `integer`** explicitly to match the return type.

**Unquoted upper case identifiers** are folded to lower case in Postgres anyway, and only serve to confuse.

I used shorter (and a bit faster) expressions for your conditional count. In Postgres 9.4 or later use an aggregate `FILTER` instead. See:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27572/3684)
- [Conditional SQL count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020065/conditional-sql-count/29022738#29022738)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [`RETURN QUERY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) and a [`setof record`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-SET) return type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_grade(IN integer, out bigint, out bigint, out bigint, out bigint)
returns setof record AS
$BODY$
begin
    return query select 
        sum(case when t.pirority = 66 then 1 else 0 end) as I,
        sum(case when t.pirority = 67 then 1 else 0 end) as II,
        sum(case when t.pirority = 68 then 1 else 0 end) as III,
        sum(case when t.pirority = 225 then 1 else 0 end) as IIII 
        from dt_info t 
        where t.registrant = $1;
end
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

You could do that as a plain SQL function as well:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_grade(IN integer, out bigint, out bigint, out bigint, out bigint)
returns setof record AS
$BODY$
    select 
        sum(case when t.pirority = 66 then 1 else 0 end) as I,
        sum(case when t.pirority = 67 then 1 else 0 end) as II,
        sum(case when t.pirority = 68 then 1 else 0 end) as III,
        sum(case when t.pirority = 225 then 1 else 0 end) as IIII 
    from dt_info t 
    where t.registrant = $1;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;
```

BTW, is `t.pirority` supposed to be `t.priority` or is that the real column name?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure If I undstand what you said very well. The follwing is just a test.

```
--create table 
skytf=> create table grade (registrant integer, pirority integer);
CREATE TABLE
skytf=> insert into grade values (1,66);
INSERT 0 1
skytf=> insert into grade values (1,66);
INSERT 0 1
skytf=> insert into grade values (1,67);
INSERT 0 1
skytf=> insert into grade values (1,67);
INSERT 0 1
skytf=> insert into grade values (1,67);
INSERT 0 1
skytf=> insert into grade values (1,68);
INSERT 0 1
skytf=> insert into grade values (1,225);
INSERT 0 1
skytf=> insert into grade values (1,225);
INSERT 0 1
skytf=> insert into grade values (1,225);
INSERT 0 1
skytf=> insert into grade values (1,225);
INSERT 0 1
skytf=> select * from grade;
 registrant | pirority 
------------+----------
          1 |       66
          1 |       66
          1 |       67
          1 |       67
          1 |       67
          1 |       68
          1 |      225
          1 |      225
          1 |      225
          1 |      225


--create function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_grade( in_reg integer ) RETURNS  RECORD AS
$$
DECLARE
    g_user record;
BEGIN
    select 
    sum(case when t.pirority = 66 then 1 else 0 end) as I ,
    sum(case when t.pirority = 67 then 1 else 0 end) as II,
    sum(case when t.pirority = 68 then 1 else 0 end) as III,
    sum(case when t.pirority = 225 then 1 else 0 end) as IIII 
    into g_user
    from grade  t 
    where t.registrant = in_reg;
    return g_user;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;          


--execute function
skytf=> select get_grade(1);
 get_grade 
-----------
 (2,3,1,4)
(1 row)
```