# Conditional SQL count

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, group-by, aggregate-filter

What is the best way to create columns which count the number of occurrences of data in a table? The table needs to be grouped by one column?
My database is PostgreSQL.

I have seen:

```
SELECT
    sum(CASE WHEN question1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ZERO,
    sum(CASE WHEN question1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ONE,
    sum(CASE WHEN question1 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TWO,
    category
FROM reviews
    GROUP BY category
```

where `question1` can have a value of either *0*, *1* or *2*.

I have also seen a version of that using `count(CASE WHEN question1 = 0 THEN 1)`

However, this becomes more cumbersome to write as the number of possible values for `question1` increases. Is there a convenient way to write this query, possibly optimizing performance?

Comment: Your version is quite reasonable, although you should include the `end` if you want it to be syntactically correct.  An alternative is Postgres's `crosstab` functionality.  I don't know which is better performance-wise.

Comment: sorry, forgot to type the end

Comment: why not to group by category and question1 and count rows in groups?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri The OP wants columns names for each value of question1 then you need to transpose the result for the required result.

Comment: @Ram, aha, ok I see know. In MSSQL it would be group by category and question and then pivoting grouping results.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri True. Pivot is what I thought of first but this is postgresql.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

In Postgres 9.4 or later, use the aggregate `FILTER` option. Typically cleanest and fastest:

```sql
SELECT category
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE question1 = 0) AS zero
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE question1 = 1) AS one
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE question1 = 2) AS two
FROM   reviews
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Details for the `FILTER` clause:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/how-can-i-simplify-this-game-statistics-query/27141193#27141193)

If you want it *short*:

```sql
SELECT category
     , count(question1 = 0 OR NULL) AS zero
     , count(question1 = 1 OR NULL) AS one
     , count(question1 = 2 OR NULL) AS two
FROM   reviews
GROUP  BY 1;
```

More syntax variants:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27572/3684)

#### Proper crosstab query

`crosstab()` yields the best performance and is shorter for long lists of options:

```sql
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
     'SELECT category, question1, count(*) AS ct
      FROM   reviews
      GROUP  BY 1, 2
      ORDER  BY 1, 2'
   , 'VALUES (0), (1), (2)'
   ) AS ct (category text, zero int, one int, two int);
```

Detailed explanation:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Answer (score 3):

The "best" way (for me) is to write a query like:

```
SELECT
    category,
    question1,
    count(*)
FROM reviews
GROUP BY category, question1
```

Then I use this data to draw a table in application logic.

Other option is to use one JSON column for all grouping results. This will result in something like:

```
category1 | {"zero": 1, "one": 3, "two": 5}
category2 | {"one": 7, "two": 4}
```

and so on.

The query for this option you can build from the previous one with `json_build_object` and `json_agg`. The best thing for this option - you do not need to know number of possible `question1` values ahead of time.