# How to use CASE statement without having to put it into GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a problem with my query. Here's my code:

```
select kpidate,reviewer as namareviewer, 
    count(formcode) as actual,
    round((0.2*count(formcode))) as target,
    CASE WHEN blibliknowledge !='' 
         THEN count(blibliknowledge)  
    END as blibli, 
    CASE WHEN solusi !=''
         THEN count(solusi)
    END as solusi
from kpi 
where kpidate >= '30/11/2015' AND kpidate<= '1/12/2015'
group by reviewer,kpidate,blibliknowledge,solusi
```

I have to add the columns `blibliknowledge` and `solusi` because of the `CASE` expression, and the output would be like this:

[image]

I want to group by `namareviewer` so 'elbert.lukman' will be grouped. So the output is just two rows. Column `blibli` and `solusi` will be calculated too as *group by namareviewer*.

Comment: Is it mysql or postgresql related question?

Comment: @Shadow I thought Querying Language between both, it's the same. Isn't it?

Comment: @Shieryn: Similar, but not the same by a long shot. Postgres is closer to standard SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to do conditional aggregation. Use an expression that returns either 1 or 0 depending on the condition, and then wrap that in a SUM aggregate. Or, have an expression return NULL and non-null values, and wrap that in a COUNT expression.

In MySQL date literals should be supplied in `'yyyy-mm-dd'` format.

As an example:

```
SELECT k.kpidate
     , k.reviewer                                               AS namareviewer
     , COUNT(k.formcode)                                        AS actual
     , ROUND((0.2*COUNT(k.formcode)))                           AS target
     , SUM(CASE WHEN k.blibliknowledge != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS blibli
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN k.solusi != '' THEN 'foo' ELSE NULL END) AS solusi
  FROM kpi k
 WHERE k.kpidate >= '2015-11-30'
   AND k.kpidate <= '2015-12-01'
 GROUP
    BY k.reviewer
     , k.kpidate
```

In MySQL, we can shorthand the `CASE` expression with a boolean expression. MySQL returns integer value 1 if the expression evaluates to TRUE, and returns a 0 if the expression evaluates to FALSE. If the expression evaluates to NULL, then it returns a NULL.

```
SELECT k.kpidate
     , k.reviewer                              AS namareviewer
     , COUNT(k.formcode)                       AS actual
     , ROUND((0.2*COUNT(k.formcode)))          AS target
     , IFNULL(SUM(k.blibliknowledge != ''),0)  AS blibli
     , IFNULL(SUM(k.solusi          != ''),0)  AS solusi
  FROM kpi k
 WHERE k.kpidate >= '2015-11-30'
   AND k.kpidate <= '2015-12-01'
 GROUP
    BY k.reviewer
     , k.kpidate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten the syntax in Postgres as well. This works for Postgres and MySQL alike:

```
SELECT kpidate
     , reviewer                             AS namareviewer
     , count(formcode)                      AS actual
     , round(count(formcode) * 0.2)         AS target
     , count(blibliknowledge <> '' OR NULL) AS blibli
     , count(solusi <> '' OR NULL)          AS solusi
FROM   kpi
WHERE  kpidate >= '2015-11-30'
AND    kpidate <  '2015-12-01'  -- typically, you'd exclude that upper bound
GROUP  BY reviewer, kpidate;
```

In Postgres 9.4, you can use the SQL standard implementation of the aggregate `FILTER` clause:

```
SELECT kpidate
     , reviewer                                      AS namareviewer
     , count(formcode)                               AS actual
     , round(count(formcode) * 0.2)                  AS target
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE blibliknowledge <> '') AS blibli
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE solusi <> '')          AS solusi
FROM   kpi
WHERE  kpidate >= '2015-11-30'
AND    kpidate <  '2015-12-01'  -- typically, you'd exclude that upper bound
GROUP  BY 1, 2;  -- another optional syntax shortcut
```

Also demonstrating a syntax shorthand that's useful when you *actually* have to reference a longish expression in the `SELECT` list - to also answer your original question.

More:

- [Conditional SQL count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020065/conditional-sql-count/29022738#29022738)
- [Concatenate multiple result rows of one column into one, group by another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847173/concatenate-multiple-result-rows-of-one-column-into-one-group-by-another-column/15850510#15850510)