# Group and count by another columns value

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like below:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test_table
(
    "ID" serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    "CID" integer NOT NULL,
    "SEG" integer NOT NULL,
    "DDN" character varying(3) NOT NULL
)
```

and data looks like this:

```
ID  CID SEG DDN
1   1   1   "711"
2   1   2   "800"
3   1   3   "124"
4   2   1   "711"
5   3   1   "711"
6   3   2   "802"
7   4   1   "799"
8   5   1   "799"
9   5   2   "804"
10  6   1   "799"
```

I need to group these data by CID column and get column counts depends on DDN columns first values but counts must give me two different information, if it's more than 1 or not.

I'm really sorry if couldn't explains clearly. Let me show you what I need..

```
DDN END TRA
711 1   2
799 2   1
```

As you can see, DDN:711 has 1 record of single count (ID:4). This is END column.
But 2 times has multiple SEG count (ID:1to3 and ID:5to6). This is TRA column.

I can not be sure what column should be in group clause!

#### My solution:

Just found a solution like below

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT
        (SELECT t1."DDN" FROM public.test_table AS t1
         WHERE t1."CID"=t."CID" AND t1."SEG"=1) AS ddn,
        COUNT("CID") AS seg_count       
    FROM public.test_table AS t
    GROUP BY "CID"
)

SELECT ddn, COUNT(seg_count) AS "TOTAL",    
    SUM(CASE WHEN x.seg_count=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "END",
    SUM(CASE WHEN x.seg_count>1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "TRA"
FROM x
GROUP BY ddn;
```

Comment: You have to give us a better explaination of what you want. I did not understand how you counted END and TRA in the example.

Comment: Sorry, again! If you look at the first 3 record, CID values are same and there are 3 record means I should count as TRA (TRAnsferred). Now lets look at 4th record, it's CID value is 2 and its single record, that means I should count that as END (ENDed).

Comment: Little more explanations;
ID:1to3 has same CID and first DDN is 711. I should count this TRA for 711.
ID:4 has single CID and first DDN is 711. I should count this END for 711.
ID:5to6 has same CID and first DDN is 711. I should count this TRA for 711.
ID:7 has single CID and first DDN is 799. I should count this END for 799.
ID:8to9 has same CID and first DDN is 799. I should count this TRA for 799.
ID:10 has single CID and first DDN is 799. I should count this END for 799.

Comment: Please do not post additional information as comments [edit] your question instead.

Comment: i see that you found a solution of your own. i also proposed you one as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalent, faster query:

```
SELECT "DDN"
     , COUNT(*) AS "TOTAL"
     , COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE seg_count = 1) AS "END"
     , COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE seg_count > 1) AS "TRA"
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON ("CID")
         "DDN"          -- assuming min "SEG" is always 1
       , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY "CID") AS seg_count
   FROM   test_table
   ORDER  BY "CID", "SEG"
   ) sub
GROUP  BY "DDN";
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e926f549d85138e95ed19d3e576e9415)*

#### Notes

CTEs are typically slower and should only be used where needed in Postgres.

This is equivalent to the query in the question *assuming* that the minimum "SEG" per "CID" is always *1* - since this query returns the row with the minimum "SEG" while your query returns the one with `"SEG" = 1`. Typically, you would want the "first" segment and my query implements this requirement more reliably, but that's not clear from the question.

`COUNT(*)` is slightly faster than `COUNT(column)` and equivalent while not involving NULL values (applicable here). Related:

- [PostgreSQL: running count of rows for a query 'by minute'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193688/postgresql-running-count-of-rows-for-a-query-by-minute/8194088#8194088)

About `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

The aggregate `FILTER` syntax requires Postgres 9.4+:

- [Conditional SQL count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020065/conditional-sql-count/29022738#29022738)

Comment: @James: I added one more improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution i propose, the query can be simplified i guess.

```
CREATE TABLE test_table
(
    ID serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    CID integer NOT NULL,
    SEG integer NOT NULL,
    DDN character varying(3) NOT NULL
);



insert into test_table(CID,SEG,DDN)
values
(   1,   1,   '711'),
(   1,   2,   '800'),
(   1,   3,   '124'),
(   2,   1,   '711'),
(   3,   1,   '711'),
(   3,   2,   '802'),
(   4,   1,   '799'),
(   5,   1,   '799'),
(   5,   2,   '804'),
(   6,   1,   '799');


with summary as (with ddn_t as (select cid,ddn,row_number() OVER( PARTITION BY cid)from test_table)
select a.cid,count(distinct a.ddn),b.ddn
 from ddn_t a 
 join ddn_t b on b.cid=a.cid and b.row_number=1
group by a.cid, b.ddn)
select ddn,
sum (case when count >1 then 1 else 0 end) as TRA,
sum (case when count = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as END
from summary
group by ddn;
```