# How I fixed the incompatible error in PostgreSQL while pivoting?

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, crosstab

I'm pivoting in PostgreSQL but when I run the query the output says:

> ```
> ERROR:  return and sql tuple descriptions are incompatible
> SQL state: 42601
> ```

Summarizing, I want the distribution channel on raw, the year in the columns and the operative margin as value.

- dist_chann_id --> integer
- year --> year
- operative_margin --> integer

Without the pivot the output is:

| dist_chann_name | year | operative_margin |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020 | 20783 |
| 1 | 2021 | 5791 |
| 2 | 2020 | 30362 |
| 3 | 2021 | 14501 |
| 3 | 2020 | 2765 |
| 3 | 2021 | 4535 |

This is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
'SELECT dist_chann_id, year, operative_margin
FROM marginality_by_channel
ORDER BY dist_chann_id, year'
     ) AS ct ("DC" int, "2020" int, "2021" int);
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: `year` is not a data type. What's the actual type? And `dist_chann_name` <> `dist_chann_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Source of the error msg

One of the columns does not have data type you think it has.  Must be `operative_margin`, probably `text`?

The 1-parameter form of `crosstab()` only uses the *"category"* column (`year` in your example) only for sorting. And the *"row_name"* column (`dist_chann_name` - or `dist_chann_id` ?) would produce a different error msg.

#### Solution

Either way, unless you can guarantee that every *"row_name"* has exactly two values to it, it's safer to use the 2-parameter form of `corosstab()`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM  crosstab(
   $$
   SELECT dist_chann_name, year, operative_margin
   FROM   marginality_by_channel
   ORDER  BY 1, 2
   $$
 , 'VALUES (2020), (2021)'
   ) AS ct ("DC" int, "2020" int, "2021" int);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=87bc22e296c13d59790346da8b17bf62)*

This variant also *happens* to be more tolerant with type mismatches (as everything is passed as `text` anyway). See:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

`crosstab()` shines for many resulting value columns (faster, shorter). For just two *"value"* columns, aggregate `FILTER` might be the better (simpler) choice. Not much performance to gain (if any, after adding some overhead). See:

- [a_horse's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69956509/939860) under this question
- [Conditional SQL count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020065/conditional-sql-count/29022738#29022738)

#### Broken setup

That aside, your **setup is ambiguous** to begin with. It includes two rows for the same `(dist_chann_name, year) = (3, 2021)`.

- a_horse uses `sum()` in his aggregate `FILTER` solution. You might also use `min()` or `max()`, or whatever ...
- My solution with the **2-parameter** form outputs the **last** value according to sort order. (Think of it as each next value overwriting it's dedicated spot.)
- The **1-parameter** form outputs the **first** value according to sort order. (Think of it as "first come, first serve". Superfluous rows are discarded.)

A clean solution would use an explicit sort order and document the effect, or work with a query producing distinct values, or use the appropriate aggregate function with the `FILTER` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using filtered aggregation is typically much easier than the somewhat convoluted `crosstab()` function (at least in my opinion).

```
select dist_chann_name as dc,
       sum(operative_margin) filter (where year = 2020) as "2020",
       sum(operative_margin) filter (where year = 2021) as "2021"
from marginality_by_channel
group by dist_chann_name
order by dist_chann_name;
```