# Create date-aggregate statistics of product sales and prices in plain SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE products 
(
    id INT,
    created_at DATE,
    sold_at DATE
);

CREATE TABLE product_prices 
(
    id INT,
    product_id INT,
    price numeric,
    created_at DATE
);
```

The data model logic works as follows:

1. When a new product is put for sale, a record is inserted into `products` with the current date as `created_at`.
2. At the same time, a record is inserted into `product_prices` with the same date in `created_at`, an FK reference to the product and a `price`.
3. If a product is sold, the `sold_at` is set on the `products` record.
4. If the product changes price throughout its sales period a new record is added to `product_prices` with the `created_at` date the `price` was changed. This means, that if you wanna know what price a product has at a given date, then you need to check what the price was at that date by looking at `product_prices`.

Now imagine that I have seed data something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products;
```

| id | created_at | sold_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-25T00:00:00.000Z | 2022-02-18T00:00:00.000Z |
| 2 | 2022-01-26T00:00:00.000Z |  |
| 3 | 2022-01-28T00:00:00.000Z | 2022-01-30T00:00:00.000Z |
| 4 | 2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z |
| 5 | 2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2022-02-15T00:00:00.000Z |
| 6 | 2022-02-10T00:00:00.000Z | 2022-02-13T00:00:00.000Z |
| 7 | 2022-02-14T00:00:00.000Z |  |
| 8 | 2022-02-19T00:00:00.000Z |  |
| 9 | 2022-02-20T00:00:00.000Z | 2022-02-22T00:00:00.000Z |
| 10 | 2022-02-22T00:00:00.000Z |  |

and

```
SELECT * FROM product_prices;
```

| id | product_id | price | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100.0 | 2022-01-25T00:00:00.000Z |
| 2 | 1 | 95.0 | 2022-02-02T00:00:00.000Z |
| 3 | 1 | 85.0 | 2022-02-17T00:00:00.000Z |
| 4 | 2 | 89.0 | 2022-01-26T00:00:00.000Z |
| 5 | 2 | 85.0 | 2022-01-30T00:00:00.000Z |
| 6 | 3 | 91.0 | 2022-01-28T00:00:00.000Z |
| 7 | 4 | 50.0 | 2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z |
| 8 | 5 | 100.0 | 2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z |
| 9 | 5 | 99.0 | 2022-02-03T00:00:00.000Z |
| 10 | 6 | 79.0 | 2022-02-10T00:00:00.000Z |
| 11 | 6 | 75.0 | 2022-02-11T00:00:00.000Z |
| 12 | 6 | 71.0 | 2022-02-12T00:00:00.000Z |
| 13 | 7 | 120.0 | 2022-02-14T00:00:00.000Z |
| 14 | 7 | 110.0 | 2022-02-16T00:00:00.000Z |
| 15 | 8 | 89.0 | 2022-02-19T00:00:00.000Z |
| 16 | 9 | 30.0 | 2022-02-20T00:00:00.000Z |
| 17 | 9 | 29.0 | 2022-02-22T00:00:00.000Z |
| 18 | 10 | 100.0 | 2022-02-22T00:00:00.000Z |

---

I want to know what was the `average price` and the `number of products for sale` and `the number of sold products` on a daily basis between `2022-01-23` and `2022-02-23`.

In pseudo SQL it would be something like:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(products_for_sale_this_day), 
    COUNT(products_sold_this_day), 
    AVG(price_of_products_for_sale_on_this_day) 
FROM 
    products ... 
WHERE 
    date "is between 2022-01-23 and 2022-02-23" 
GROUP BY 
    "dates in between"`
```

The result I would expect from the seed data would be:

| Products for sale | Number of sold | Avg price | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0.0 | 2022-01-23 |
| 0 | 0 | 0.0 | 2022-01-24 |
| 1 | 0 | xx.xx | 2022-01-25 |
| 2 | 0 | xx.xx | 2022-01-26 |
| 2 | 0 | xx.xx | 2022-01-27 |
| 3 | 0 | xx.xx | 2022-01-28 |
| 3 | 0 | xx.xx | 2022-01-29 |
| 3 | 1 | 92.0 | 2022-01-30 |
| 2 | 0 | xx.xx | 2022-01-31 |
| 4 | 1 | xx.xx | 2022-02-01 |
| 3 | 0 | xx.xx | 2022-02-02 |
| 3 | 0 | xx.xx | 2022-02-03 |
| 3 | 0 | xx.xx | 2022-02-04 |
| 3 | 0 | xx.xx | 2022-02-05 |
| 3 | 0 | xx.xx | 2022-02-06 |
| 3 | 0 | xx.xx | 2022-02-07 |
| 3 | 0 | xx.xx | 2022-02-08 |
| 3 | 0 | xx.xx | 2022-02-09 |
| 4 | 0 | xx.xx | 2022-02-10 |
| 4 | 0 | xx.xx | 2022-02-11 |
| 4 | 0 | xx.xx | 2022-02-12 |
| 4 | 1 | xx.xx | 2022-02-13 |
| 4 | 0 | xx.xx | 2022-02-14 |
| 4 | 1 | xx.xx | 2022-02-15 |
| 3 | 0 | xx.xx | 2022-02-16 |
| 3 | 0 | xx.xx | 2022-02-17 |
| 3 | 1 | xx.xx | 2022-02-18 |
| 3 | 0 | xx.xx | 2022-02-19 |
| 4 | 0 | xx.xx | 2022-02-20 |
| 4 | 0 | xx.xx | 2022-02-21 |
| 5 | 1 | xx.xx | 2022-02-22 |
| 4 | 0 | xx.xx | 2022-02-23 |

**NOTE:** I added `xx.xx` as I didn't want to manually calculate the `AVG` for every day in the example. On the `2022-01-30` the average price comes from the following products being for sale with the following prices:

- Product ID 1, price at `2022-01-30`: `100.0`
- Product ID 2, price at `2022-01-30`: `85.0`
- Product ID 3, price at `2022-01-30`: `91.0`

AVG: `(100 + 85 + 91) / 3 = 92`

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jxQAqLvnKExjTVr16XyonG/0

Comment: Can you also explain the logic that you using to calculate the ```products for sale``` and ```number of sold```. Based on which date you are calculating these metrics, is it coming from the ```products``` table or the ```product_prices``` table? Please clarify on these.

Comment: No, so the number of `products for sale` at a given date is: Any `product` `WHERE created_at <= the_particular_date AND (sold_at >= the_particular_date OR sold_at IS NULL)` as `sold_at IS NULL` means that the product is still for sale (has not been sold). For `number of sold` that would be `WHERE sold_at = the_particular_date` for prices, see my comment on @jian's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT d.the_day                                        AS "Date"
     , count(p.id)                                      AS "Products for sale"
     , count(p.id) FILTER (WHERE p.sold_at = d.the_day) AS "Number of sold"
     , round(coalesce(avg(pp.price), 0), 2)             AS "Avg price"
FROM  (
   SELECT ts::date AS the_day 
   FROM   generate_series (timestamp '2022-01-23'
                         , timestamp '2022-02-23'
                         , interval  '1 day') ts
   ) d
LEFT  JOIN products p ON p.created_at <= d.the_day
                     AND (p.sold_at < d.the_day) IS NOT TRUE
LEFT  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT pp.price
   FROM   product_prices pp
   WHERE  pp.product_id = p.id
   AND    pp.created_at <= d.the_day
   ORDER  BY pp.created_at DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) pp ON true
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xvZz5v-o)

I only join to products that are already listed and not yet sold to begin with. The day of the sale is included. Notably, products sold "today" are counted among "for sale" as well as among "sold", like your expected result demonstrates.

You show type `date`, but `timestamptz` literals. I went with dates like in your fiddle. Data types matter ...

Why did I use `generate_series()` this way?

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)

About the `LATERAL` join:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

About getting the latest applicable price:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)

About the aggregate `FILTER` clause:

- [Conditional SQL count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020065/conditional-sql-count/29022738#29022738)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   G.DATE
  , COUNT(DISTINCT(products.id)) FOR_SALES
  , COUNT(DISTINCT( 
        CASE WHEN PRODUCTS.SOLD_AT::DATE=G.DATE 
        THEN products.id ELSE NULL END)) SOLD
  , AVG(PP.PRICE) AVE_PRICE
FROM
generate_series(date '2022-01-23' , date '2022-02-23' , interval '1 day') g (date)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
products  
    ON G.DATE BETWEEN PRODUCTS.CREATED_AT AND COALESCE(PRODUCTS.SOLD_AT,CURRENT_DATE)
INNER JOIN  
   (SELECT price,product_id,created_at price_created_at,coalesce(lead(created_at)over(partition by product_id order by ID asc),current_date)::TIMESTAMP-interval '1 second' to_date FROM product_prices) pp 
  ON pp.product_id = products.id and G.DATE between pp.price_created_at and pp.to_date 
GROUP BY  G.DATE
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hBBt3jcVnXXRV5pL1yn1yc/0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The last table in Original post, last part should be like:

```
    date    | products_for_sale |
 2022-02-21 |                 4 |              
 2022-02-22 |                 5 |             
 2022-02-23 |                 4 |
```

Main query:

```
SELECT
    sub2.*
    , CASE WHEN p1.sold_at IS NOT NULL THEN
        1
    ELSE
        0
    END AS number_of_sold
FROM (
    SELECT
        date
        , count(id) AS products_for_sale
    FROM (
        SELECT
            date::date
            , p.*
        FROM
            generate_series(date '2022-01-23' , date '2022-02-23' , interval '1 day') g (date)
            LEFT JOIN products p ON date >= p.created_at
                AND date <= coalesce(sold_at , '2022-02-23')
            ORDER BY
                id
                , date) sub
    GROUP BY
        1) sub2
    LEFT JOIN products P1 ON p1.sold_at = sub2.date
ORDER BY
    sub2.date;
```

Make previous query as view (test_2) for simplicity. Then do one more time left join.

```
SELECT
    sub1.*, price
FROM (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        test_2) sub1
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (1 , 2)
            product_id
            , sold_at AS date
            , pp.created_at AS price_crearted_at
            , price
        FROM
            products p
            JOIN product_prices pp ON pp.product_id = p.id
        WHERE
            sold_at IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY
            1
            , 2
            , 3 DESC) sub2 USING (date)
ORDER BY
    date;
```

If you join `products` with `product_prices` you will found out that same product have multiple price entry. Since in products, id is unique, meaning every product only sold once, so to get the latest price (order by price_crearted_at desc) of a product in `product_prices`, use `distinct on` and with `order by price_crearted_at desc`

Comment: Okay, got it. That part might be unclear: So the point is, the price of a `product` at a given date, is the most recent entry in `product_prices` from that date OR earlier. Because the prices in `product_prices` table are added when a price of product changes (to track price history). So in product ID 1's case, it's the record with ID 1 from `product_prices` which is the "current price" at 2022-01-30. The same is the case for product ID 3. Is it more clear now?

Comment: @NielsKristian updated. let me know it works or not.

Comment: Thanks for the response - and you are right about the table - I changed it in the post. The queries on AVG price does not seem to work though. I tried adding it here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jxQAqLvnKExjTVr16XyonG/1 and it seems to be taking the price of the sold ones. What I need is the AVG price of ALL the products for sale that day with their respective price at that day (including those that got sold that day). Am I explaining it well enough?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/A-4EOLQw  let me know if this is what you want. @NielsKristian

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But unfortunately this is not quite it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(product_prices.product_id) as Productsforsale, count(sold_at) Numberofsold ,
avg(price) Avgprice , date(sold_at) as Date FROM products JOIN product_prices 
ON products.id = product_prices.product_id group by sold_at
order by sold_at
```

[image]