# SQL (standard) join count by several columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, aggregate-filter

I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE poster (
    poster_id SERIAL NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY,
    country VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE batch (
    batch_id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    price VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE poster 
    ADD COLUMN batch_id SERIAL REFERENCES batch (batch_id);

INSERT INTO batch (price) VALUES (10)
INSERT INTO batch (price) VALUES (11)

INSERT INTO poster (country, batch_id) VALUES ('DEU', 1);
INSERT INTO poster (country, batch_id) VALUES ('DEU', 1);
INSERT INTO poster (country, batch_id) VALUES ('FRA', 1);
```

I want get how many posters I have for a particular country, for the rest of the world and the total, grouped by batch.

This code solves the problem, but I want to know if there's a more performant query.

```
SELECT 
    batch.batch_id, 
    germany.count AS germany, 
    other.count AS outside, 
    total.count AS total 
FROM
    batch 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         poster.batch_id AS batch_id, 
         COUNT(*) AS count 
     FROM
         poster 
     WHERE
         poster.country = 'DEU' 
     GROUP BY
         poster.batch_id) AS germany ON germany.batch_id = batch.batch_id
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
         poster.batch_id AS batch_id, 
         COUNT(*) AS count 
     FROM
         poster 
     WHERE
         poster.country <> 'DEU' 
     GROUP BY
         poster.batch_id) AS other ON other.batch_id = batch.batch_id
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
         poster.batch_id AS batch_id, 
         COUNT(*) AS count 
     FROM
         poster 
     GROUP BY
         poster.batch_id) AS total ON total.batch_id = batch.batch_id
```

Also when the batch doesn't have any poster I want to return 0 instead of null.

Comment: use COALESCE like https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-coalesce/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern (>=9.4) PostgreSQL (that you tagged the question with), you can use a `filter` clause on an aggregate function and use that to apply conditions on the rows effected by the function. With this technique, you can reduce the query to a single `left join`:

```sql
SELECT    b.batch_id, germany, outside, total
FROM      batch b
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   batch_id,
                    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE country = 'DEU') AS germany,
                    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE country <> 'DEU') AS outside,
                    COUNT(*) AS total
           FROM     poster
           GROUP BY batch_id) p ON b.batch_id = p.batch_id
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a9190/2/0)

If you don't want to use PostgreSQL-specific syntax, you could use `case` expressions instead:

```sql
SELECT    b.batch_id, germany, outside, total
FROM      batch b
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   batch_id,
                    COUNT(CASE country WHEN 'DEU' THEN 1 END) AS germany,
                    COUNT(CASE country WHEN 'DEU' THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) AS outside,
                    COUNT(*) AS total
           FROM     poster
           GROUP BY batch_id) p ON b.batch_id = p.batch_id
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a9190/3/0)

Comment: FILTER is actually ANSI/ISO SQL syntax, (optional) features T612, "Advanced OLAP operators", T611, "Elementary OLAP operations". However. I don't know any dbms but Postgresql supporting it.

Comment: @jarlh it's been a while since I read the ANSI/SQL standard. Wasn't aware of that, thanks for pointing it out! Having said that, on a practical note, if you're looking for SQL code that can easily be ported to other RBDMSs, you should probably shy away from `filter` clauses (as you mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

> Also when the batch doesn't have any poster I want to return 0 instead of null.

You get 0 instead of `null` with a `LATERAL` subquery:

```sql
SELECT b.batch_id, germany, total - germany AS other, total
FROM   batch b
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT count(*) FILTER (WHERE country = 'DEU') AS germany
        , count(*) AS total
   FROM   poster p
   WHERE  p.batch_id = b.batch_id
   ) p ON true;
```

See:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
- [Conditional SQL count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020065/conditional-sql-count/29022738#29022738)
- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

Also, 2 counts are cheaper than 3.

While processing all batches anyway, a plain subquery is cheaper.
Wrap counts in [`COALESCE()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) in the outer `SELECT` list to get0 instead of  null:

```sql
SELECT b.batch_id
     , COALESCE(germany, 0) AS germany
     , COALESCE(total - germany, 0) AS other
     , COALESCE(total, 0) AS total
FROM   batch b
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT batch_id
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE country = 'DEU') AS germany
--      , count(country = 'DEU' OR null) AS germany  -- alternative
        , count(*) AS total
   FROM   poster
   GROUP  BY batch_id
   ) p USING (batch_id);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EUjBjcmC)

About various counting techniques:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27572/3684)